# JavaFX CSS styling a TreeTableView to remove indentation

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am styling a `TreeTableView` in CSS and I want to remove the spacing for all children. See image below.

Also are there any CSS generators for JavaFX?

[image]

I have tried this :

```
.tree-table-view {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
    -fx-start-margin: 0px;
    -fx-end-margin: 0px;
}
.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
    -fx-font-size:16px;
    -fx-start-margin: 0px;
    -fx-end-margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: In SceneBuilder go to View->Show CSS Analyzer here you can see all the names of all items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the indent with

```
.tree-table-row-cell {
    -fx-indent: 0;
}
```

**Note:** The width of the arrow area will still be indented, but in my opinion it is expected and necessary:

[image]

If you lower the indent even more (-10, -20) you can also remove the arrows if needed.